Ubuntu 22.04 boots into console instead of GUI
I have a Ubuntu 22.04.04
when booting he loads the console instead of the GUI
I tried to run sudo apt update sudo apt --fix-broken install and sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target i didnt get errors but they didn't work.
I also tried sudo apt-get clean
then I tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop but got massive error lines of failed to fetch files.
I managed to access the GUI whit startx but it is not automatic and it is different from normal loading (no desktop-only activities)
can someone help me solve this problem? many thanks!

Can you post the massive error lines please?

a lot of lines that tell he can't  fetch some files form the archive

Can you post them so that we can see exactly what's the problem?
